# If running webpack programmatically he doesn't find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, build, electron

I want to use webpack-api at my electron app for build external web project.

I decide using [webpack API](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/) in my app, but webpack can't found the babel-loader.

I created simple repository to reproduce the error: [repository](https://github.com/ararati/webpack-api-node-issue)

Abstract presentation of the project (A - electron app, B - web project for build)

Error msg:

```
main.js:1 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\User\B\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js'
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/loader-runner/lib_lazy_namespace_object?:5)
    at eval (main.js:1)
```

Base structure of both project:

```
Project A:
- main.js
- node_modules/
- webpack.config.js

Project B:
- main.js
- node_modules/
- webpack.config.js
```

Every project is independent and has all tool for development(like webpack)

My webpack config in project A for run webpack (if I using '/' in path I get API Schema error at webpack):

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    target: "web",
    entry: "D:\\User\\B\\src\\main.js",
    context: "D:\\User\\B\\",
    output: {
        path: "D:\\A",
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/i,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
        'D:\\User\\B\\node_modules',   //the same error if remove this line   
        ],
    },

    stats: {
        errorDetails: true
    },
}
```

Run webpack:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('./webpack.config');
const compiler = webpack(config);

compiler.run((err, stats) => {
   //output errors...
});
```

**Important**:

1. If to try build project B using webpack cli (through npm), no
   errors.
2. Project A based on **Electron**.
3. Using library version on both project: babel-loader^8.1.0, @babel/core^7.9.0, webpack^4.42.1, electron^8.2.1(electron only at A project)
4. Bundle file is created
5. Bundle js file is using in HTML file

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this server already has other webpack wich running in watch mode and constanlty removing packages. Try to reload the server